# Swift parsing json doesn't work

Tags: ios, json, swift

I want to parse a json file, this is in my json file:

```
{
    "currentPowerByClient": 0,  <- i want to read this
    "currentPowerToClient":518,
    "tariff":1,
    "totalGasDelivered":1061.004,
    "totalPowerByClientHigh":10.704,
    "totalPowerByClientLow":23.042,
    "totalPowerToClientHigh":912.221,
    "totalPowerToClientLow": 693.499
}
```

this is my swift code, the object called `JSONResult` contains my `JSON` code

```
var jsonResult: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options:
NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as NSDictionary

if let item = jsonResult as NSDictionary? {
    if let currentPowerByClient = item["currentPowerByClient"] as? NSDictionary {
        println(currentPowerByClient)
    }
}
```

when i run it, it doesn't print anything

Comment: maybe you should use the error parameter; it would be helpful to know if jsonResult is just nil or something different than an NSDictionary

Comment: i don't get any errors, maybe jsonResult is nil, but i don't know why it's nil

Comment: so you did change your code to actually use the error parameter and you did not get any error or did you not get any error with above code?

Comment: i just don't get a error maybe my way of parsing the json is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
if let currentPowerByClient = item["currentPowerByClient"] as? NSDictionary
```

should be

```
if let currentPowerByClient = item["currentPowerByClient"] as? NSNumber
```

because `item["currentPowerByClient"]` is expected to be a number, not a dictionary. it works then